# 別のPCのMySQLに接続できない

Tags: mysql

自宅にあるサーバー用PCのMySQLに、自宅の別のPCからアクセスしたいのですができません。
MySQLのバージョンは8.0です。

サーバー用PCと同じIPアドレス内にある別のPCから

```
mysql -u admin -p
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

としても接続できず

```
mysql -h 'IPアドレス' -u admin -p 
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'IPアドレス' (10061)
```

と、自宅のIPアドレスを入力しても接続できません。

以下の要件は満たしています。

- bind-addressは設定していない。
- ファイアーウォールで3306は開放している。
- MySQLのポートは3306に設定している。
- adminは全てのIPアドレスからアクセスできるように設定している。

どのようにしたらよいでしょうか。

Comment: 「要件は満たしています」の部分は、そう判断した情報=コマンドの実行結果なども質問文に含めてもらうとよいかもしれません。

Comment: pingは通ってますか？`Can't connect to MySQL ..` というメッセージはネットワーク的に サーバーに接続できてないと思います。

Answer (score 1):

mysqlのアカウントはホスト名を含めて管理されています。
そのため、アカウント名としては　アカウント名＠接続ホスト名
でアクセスする必要があります。

https://www.dbonline.jp/mysql/connect/index3.html

接続元ホスト名の情報が正しくなければアクセスできないため、
以下の手順を試してみてはいかがでしょうか？

http://ext.omo3.com/linux/mysql_host.html